# How to eliminate white lines in HTML emails mostly seen on iPhone

Tags: iphone, email, line

I'm trying to get rid of these white lines that iPhone users are seeing in these emails. This can be reproduced by viewing the email in chrome when re-sizing the browser. Whether the white lines appear or not depends on the size of the window. It only happens to the image slices of the left-most data-cell in a table-row.

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html charset=UTF-8" />

    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        /***START, CSS targeting client bugs***/

        body {
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
            -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
            /* Prevents Webkit and Windows Mobile platforms from changing default font sizes. */
        }

        .ExternalClass {
            width: 100%;
            /* Forces Hotmail to display emails at full width */
        }

        .ExternalClass,
        .ExternalClass p,
        .ExternalClass span,
        .ExternalClass font,
        .ExternalClass td,
        .ExternalClass div {
            line-height: 100%;
            /* Forces Hotmail to display normal line spacing */
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            /* Resets all body margins and padding to 0 for good measure */
        }

        p {
            margin: 1em 0;
        }

        table td {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            /*This resolves the Outlook 07, 10, and Gmail td padding issue */
        }

        @-ms-viewport {
            width: device-width;
        }
        /***END, CSS targeting client bugs***/
        /***START, Reset styles***/

        p {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }

        h1,
        h2,
        h3,
        h4,
        h5,
        h6 {
            color: black;
            line-height: 100%;
        }
        /***END, Reset styles***/

        @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
            a[href^="tel"],
            a[href^="sms"] {
                text-decoration: underline;
                color: #0063ba;
                pointer-events: none;
                cursor: default;
            }
            .mobile_link a[href^="tel"],
            .mobile_link a[href^="sms"] {
                text-decoration: underline;
                color: #0063ba !important;
                pointer-events: auto;
                cursor: default;
            }
            body {
                overflow-x: hidden !important;
                text-align: center !important;
                background-color: #ffffff !important;
            }
            body[yahoo] .container {
                width: 320px !important;
                display: block !important;
            }
            body[yahoo] .drop {
                width: 100% !important;
                display: block !important;
                text-align: center !important;
                padding: 2px 0 !important;
            }
            body[yahoo] .hide_this {
                display: none !important;
            }
            body[yahoo] .respond_to_width {
                width: 100% !important;
                display: block !important;
            }
            body[yahoo] .mobile_image {
                width: 100% !important;
                height: auto !important;
            }
            body[yahoo] .pushto100 {
                width: 100% !important;
            }
            body[yahoo] .centerthis {
                text-align: center !important;
                display: inline-block !important;
            }
        }
    </style>

</head>
<custom name="opencounter" type="tracking">

    <body style="margin: 0px; padding:0px; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; -ms-text-size-adjust: none;" yahoo="fix">
        <!--CENTER EMAIL_start-->
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" class="respond_to_width">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" valign="top">
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;font-family:arial,sans-serif;color:#333333;padding:10px 0;">
                                            <a href="%%view_email_url%%" alias="VAWP" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: underline;color:#333333;">Click to view this message in a browser</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" valign="top">
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="640" class="respond_to_width">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="top">
                                            <a conversion="TRUE" alias="body_header" href="https://www.google.com"><img class="mobile_image" style="display:block;" border="0" src="http://i.imgsafe.org/84aa6e6.png" width="640" height="143" alt="email header" title="start shopping"></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="left" valign="top">
                                            <a conversion="TRUE" alias="body_zone1" href="https://www.google.com"><img class="mobile_image" style="display:block;" border="0" src="http://i.imgsafe.org/87ba827.png" width="321" height="192" alt="clickzone 1" title="shop Halloween costmes"></a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="left" valign="top">
                                            <a conversion="TRUE" alias="body_zone2" href="https://www.google.com"><img class="mobile_image" style="display:block;" border="0" src="http://i.imgsafe.org/8b26eb0.png" width="319" height="192" alt="clickzone 2" title="shop Halloween costmes"></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="left" valign="top">
                                            <a conversion="TRUE" alias="body_zone3" href="https://www.google.com"><img class="mobile_image" style="display:block;" border="0" src="http://i.imgsafe.org/8c23711.png" width="321" height="159" alt="clickzone 3"></a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="left" valign="top">
                                            <a conversion="TRUE" alias="body_zone4" href="https://www.google.com"><img class="mobile_image" style="display:block;" border="0" src="http://i.imgsafe.org/8d3de4a.png" width="319" height="159" alt="clickzone 4" title="shop Halloween costmes"></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="left" valign="top">
                                            <a conversion="TRUE" alias="body_zone5" href="https://www.google.com"><img class="mobile_image" style="display:block;" border="0" src="http://i.imgsafe.org/8e4baa8.png" width="321" height="191" alt="clickzone 5" title="shop Halloween costmes"></a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="left" valign="top">
                                            <a conversion="TRUE" alias="body_zone6" href="https://www.google.com"><img class="mobile_image" style="display:block;" border="0" src="http://i.imgsafe.org/9053862.png" width="319" height="191" alt="clickzone 6" title="shop Halloween costmes"></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="top">
                                            <a conversion="TRUE" alias="body_footer" href="https://www.google.com"><img class="mobile_image" style="display:block;" border="0" src="http://i.imgsafe.org/9226e55.png" width="640" height="181" alt="email footer" title="contact us, etc"></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:0%;padding:10px 0 0 0;display:none;">
                                %%=ContentAreaByName("Divider_Green")=%%
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!--SOCIAL BUTTONS/-->
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="left" valign="top">
                                            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" alias="Facebook" target="_blank"> FaceBook </a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td align="left" valign="top">
                                            <a href="https://plus.google.com/" alias="Google+" target="_blank">
                                                                    Google+
                                                                </a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td align="left" valign="top">
                                            <a href="https://instagram.com/" alias="Instagram" target="_blank">
                                                                    InstaGram
                                                                </a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td align="left" valign="top">
                                            <a href="http://www.pinterest.com/" alias="Pinterest" target="_blank">
                                                                    Pintrest
                                                                </a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td align="left" valign="top">
                                            <a href="https://twitter.com/" alias="Twitter" target="_blank">
                                                                    Twitter
                                                                </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!--EMAIL, PHONE NUMBER/-->

                        <tr>

                            <td align="center" valign="top">
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="drop" align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:14px;font-family:arial,sans-serif;color:#6ebe43;padding:0 20px 0 0;">
                                            <a href="mailto:customerservice@chasing-fireflies.com" alias="customerservice@chasing-fireflies.com" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;color:#88ab00;">customerservice@arbitraryLink.com </a>
                                            <span style="font-size:14px;font-family:arial,sans-serif;color:#000001">
                                        | 1.888.777.6666
                                    </span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="drop" align="center" valign="middle">
                                            <!--CTA BUTTON/-->
                                            <br>
                                            <br>
                                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="pushto100">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="left" valign="middle" style="padding:0 10px">
                                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:12px;color:#88ab00;font-family:arial,sans-serif;font-weight:bold;">

                                                                    <span style="text-decoration: none;color:#88ab00;">
                                                                    <a href="https://www.google.com" alias="signUpButton" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;color:#88ab00;">sign up for emails</a></span>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                            <!--<br><br>-->
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="640" align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;font-family:arial,sans-serif;color:#6ebe43;padding:16px 4px;">
                                <span style="color:#333333; width:640px;"> 
                           *Terms and conditions apply
                             <br><br>
                          This email was sent by: %%member_busname%%, %%member_addr%% %%member_city%%, %%member_state%% %%member_postalcode%% %%member_country%%</span>
                                <br>
                                <span style="color:#333333;">
                            This email was sent to: <strong>%%emailaddr%%</strong></span><span style="color:#333333;">. We respect your right to privacy -</span> <a href="http://www.chasing-fireflies.com/full-privacy/content" alias="PRIVACY POLICY" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;color:#88ab00;">privacy policy</a>
                                <br>
                                <br>
                                <a href="%%unsub_center_url%%" alias="One-Click Unsubscribe" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;color:#88ab00;">One-Click Unsubscribe</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <!--CENTER EMAIL_end-->
        %%[ var @additionalattribute1, @additionalattribute2, @additionalattribute3, @additionalattribute4 Set @additionalattribute1 = __AdditionalEmailAttribute1 Set @additionalattribute2 = __AdditionalEmailAttribute2 Set @additionalattribute3 = __AdditionalEmailAttribute3 Set @additionalattribute4 = __AdditionalEmailAttribute4 ]%%
        <img src="http://track.securedopen-q.com/?sv_cid=0215_01811&sv_emopen=true&sv_svem=%%emailaddr%%&cm_source=tracking_pixel_stuff" height="1" width="1" />
    </body>

</html>
```

You can see the white lines in my jFiddle when resizing the browser in chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/stormbloom/4s0sqkbb/

Please ignore the AMP script unless you think in could be causing rendering problems (which I doubt). I just left it in there so you can see what the entirety of the code looks like.

Answer (score 4):

I discovered if I add an in-line style: outline 1px solid #f00; to the table, it fixes the white line issue. The problem is that many email clients do not support outline, but they add a space where outline is being used. So it causes the table you target to have a noticeable white space in that email client.

To fix this issue and only target iphone and devices using webkit is to create a class called .iphone and add it to a media query which targets iPhone 5, 6 and 6 plus.

```
  @media only screen and (max-width: 414px) {
    .iphone {
      outline: 1px solid #f00;
  }
```

Add the class "iphone" to the table with the white line issue. This fixes the white line issue and only shows on devices that can work with that media query. This tested with Litmus and with observing on the actual devices.